# Taiga not sending email invite to add members

Tags: email, curl, proxy, smtp, taiga

1. When i am setting taiga on localhost it is not sending email invite to the members it says Everything is ok if member is already registered on taiga they will get the email directly

Email Configuration of taiga is :-
version: "3.5"

## Email settings.

EMAIL_BACKEND: "django.core.mail.backends.${EMAIL_BACKEND}.EmailBackend"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: "care@anderbaher.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS: "False"
EMAIL_USE_SSL: "True"
EMAIL_HOST: "smtpout.secureserver.net"
EMAIL_PORT: "465"
EMAIL_HOST_USER: "xxxxxxx"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxx"

2. when i am using curl command to test emails it shows everything ok but not sends the emails to the recipent
   command :-curl --url 'smtps://smtpout.secureserver.net:465' --mail-from 'care@anderbaher.com' --mail-rcpt 'vinit.sankhe@anderbaher.com' -T - --ssl-reqd --user 'xxxxxx:xxxxxx' -v

It says ok but invite is not being send

3. smtp :-
   There is no smtp erro`your text`r as i have smtp connected to the wordpress. Which is working fine and emails are working correctly

4)And there is no proxy settings . Are there proxy settings to be done

the result should be the email notification to be get which it is showing pending in my case